# No Stream.ReadByteAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, stream, async-await

I'm writing a game server using it's own protocol on top of TCP.
The packets are of the form varint packet_length followed by that amount of bytes.

To read a varint, I must read byte by byte. But Stream or NetworkStream does not provide a ReadByteAsync method, which means the task and therefore the thread will block if there is no data available from the socket yet. Of course I would wrap NetworkSteam with a BufferedStream but even BufferedStream's ReadByte uses synchronous Read to read to it's buffer. This will block.

This is how the server roughly looks like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 25000));
    while (true)
    {
        var client = listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().Result;
        HandleClient(client).ContinueWith(t => {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.Exception);
            }
        });
    }
}

public static async Task HandleClient(TcpClient client)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    while (true)
    {
        // read packet
        // using ReadByte here would block if data is not available, which means I'm wasting a thread?
    }
}
```

Why is ReadByteAsync not there? Or am I missing something?

Comment: How about `ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1)`

Comment: @IvanStoev wouldn't that be quite wasteful? The reason I wanted to use BufferedStream was to reduce the number of system calls.

Comment: Well, the default implementation of `ReadByte` [does just that](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,8b5e336542fa849f), but synchronously. Most likely the BCL designers decided that there is no need to provide similar method and implementation for `ReadByteAsync`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I wish BufferedStream had ReadByteAsync at least. It's ReadByte uses buffering :/

Comment: That's the whole purpose of Buffering, IO operations are so slow, and excessive calls to ReadByte without buffering cause serious slow down of your application. I had experienced 10 seconds slow downs, and when I used buffering whole task finished in few milliseconds.

Comment: I believe Base stream class shouldn't have provided ReadByte in the first place anyway. ReadByte only makes sense (and acceptable) when ur using a buffered stream. I like the approach Go takes. Using interfaces (Reader, Writer, Seeker, ByteReader, etc). But I think C# didn't have interfaces back then.

Comment: check out `DataReader`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the already existing method [ReadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813), bending it in your favor:

```
private static async Task<byte> ReadByteAsync(Stream s)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

    await s.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);

    return buffer[0];
}
```

Homework for ya: factor out the `buffer` into a class-level field so it doesn't get created each method call.

Comment: So pretty much rolling out a BufferedStream with ReadByteAsync support? :)

Comment: Warning! do not do this . if `ReadByteAsync` was needed it would be added! this may introduce performance problems if you read every byte asynchronously and when underlying stream does not have internal buffer or does not handle that efficiently. I did this and you must know excessive calls to ReadByteAsync is a LOT slower that reading bigger chunks asynchronously and then using it synchronously.

Comment: So I suggest you to read a big chunk asynchronously into buffer and consume that buffer synchronously.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I think that's why AgentFire suggested refactoring the buffer into a class field (as an internal buffer). Then I could read to the big internal buffer asynchronously when needed, and then return bytes from that. That's pretty much like rolling out a bufferedStream like I said :/

Comment: Note that [Stream.ReadAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readasync?view=net-8.0) may return w/o actually reading anything into the buffer in case of end of stream. You may want to add a check for the return value or use [Stream.ReadExactlyAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readexactlyasync?view=net-8.0) instread.